# Non-calculator 3rd order equation

Tags: sequences-and-series

> A geometric sequence has first term $a$, common ratio $r$ and sum to infinity $76$. A second geometric sequence has first term $a$, common ratio $r^3$and sum to infinity $36$. Find $r$.

$$\frac{a}{1-r} = 76$$
$$\frac{a}{1-r^3} = 36$$

$$\therefore \frac{1-r^3}{1-r} = \frac{76}{36}$$

Using synthetic division,

1 | -1  0  0  1

```
| -1 -1 -1 | 0
```

$$\therefore -x^2-x-1$$...is a factor.

However, $$(1-x)(-x^2-x-1) = r^3-1\neq 1-r^3$$

What's wrong? How can I solve this non-calculator question?

Comment: "What's wrong?" The sign.

Comment: $\frac{1-r^3}{1-r}=r^2+r+1$ and you are let with a quadratic.

Comment: What is wrong with the synthetic division?

Comment: @Arjun I am not familiar with synthetic division, but I guess if you write to the left "1" you are to divide by $r-1$ (a monic polynomial), not $1-r$. This sign difference gives you extra minus in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have factored it as $(1-r)(r^2+r+1)=1-r^3$. I can't exactly see what you have done with your synthethic division and why it is wrong. Here is a way to see it:

First notice, that $(1-r^3)-\color{red}{r^2}\color{blue}{(1-r)} = 1-r^2$, then, in the same way $(1-r^2)-\color{red}{r}\color{blue}{(1-r)} = \color{red}{1}\cdot \color{blue}{(1-r)}$, so adding up all red terms we have $1-r^3=\color{red}{(r^2+r+1)}\color{blue}{(1-r)}$.

So $r^2+r+1=\frac{76}{36}$. This gives $r^2+r+\frac14=\frac{49}{36}$, hence $\left(r+\frac12\right)^2=\frac{49}{36}$, hence $\left(r+\frac12\right)=\pm\frac{7}{6}$ and hence $r=\frac{4}{6}=\frac23$ or $r=-\frac{10}{6}=-\frac53$.

Comment: How did you get $r^2 + r + 1$?

Comment: And how do you get colored expressions?  Wanted to use that in my answer.

Comment: @OscarLanzi http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10116/236048

Comment: @OscarLanzi One may also press Edit under the post, look at/copy the interesting piece of the text and then press Cancel.

Answer (score 2):

Watch your signs as @ag says.  When you do synthetic division you are dividing by $x-a$ (here, $a=1$) , not $a-x$.  Thus from your result:

$-r^3+1=\color{blue}{(r-1)}(-r^2-r-1)$ not $(1-r)(-r^2-r-1)$.